# Can't access 2nd site (sub) dashboard of Wordpress Multisite

Tags: multisite, htaccess

I can't access the dashboard of the second site. When I go to the second site, I only see the HTML page without the style (css).

When I try to access the dashboard (from Safari), I get this message from the browser: "too many redirects occurred trying to open".

Subsite set-up

example.com (works)

example.com/secondary (doesn't work)

I tried disabling all plugins and change to the default theme. It still doesn't work. Here's what in my .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Aynı sorun bende de olmuştu kök dizini kontrol et bence

Answer (score 0):

This works with MAMP

Go to your htdocs folder and put all those files in a folder (name of folder will be what comes after the /). Reinstall wordpress and put all its components in another folder in htdocs. Then when opening your site you should get an index of both sites.

Answer (score 0):

```
define('MULTISITE', true); 
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false); 
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'https://hotgossips.in'); 
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/'); 
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1); 
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1); 
define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', false );
```

Just put your full address in website url whether it's from www or https or https://www

After searching for a day i found my solution. This works for me.Hope it will work for you as well!!